# Capture word after pattern with slash

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I want to extract word1 from:

```
something /CLIENT_LOGIN:word1 something else
```

I would like to extract the first word after matching pattern `/CLIENT_LOGIN:`.

Without the slash, something like this works:

```
A=something /CLIENT_LOGIN:word1 something else
B=$(echo $A | awk '$1 == "CLIENT_LOGIN" { print $2 }' FS=":")
```

With the slash though, I can't get it working (I tried putting `/` and `\/` in front of `CLIENT_LOGIN`). I don't care getting it done with `awk`, `grep`, `sed`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```sh
s='=something /CLIENT_LOGIN:word1 something else'
sed -E 's~.* /CLIENT_LOGIN:([^[:blank:]]+).*~\1~' <<< "$s"

word1
```

**Details:**

- We use `~` as regex delimiter in `sed`
- `/CLIENT_LOGIN:([^[:blank:]]+)` matches `/CLIENT_LOGIN:` followed by 1+ non-whitespace characters that is captured in group #1
- `.*` on both sides matches text before and after our match
- `\1` is used in substitution to put 1st group's captured value back in output

Comment: Tried the exact code with A="/CLIENT_IPADDR:23.4.28.2 /CLIENT_LOGIN:xdfmb1d /MXJ_C" and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Performing a regex match and capturing the resulting string in `BASH_REMATCH[]`:

```
$ regex='.*/CLIENT_LOGIN:([^[:space:]]*).*'

$ A='something /CLIENT_LOGIN:word1 something else'
$ unset B

$ [[ "${A}" =~ $regex ]] && B="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
$ echo "${B}"
word1
```

Verifying `B` remains undefined if we don't find our match:

```
$ A='something without the desired string'
$ unset B

$ [[ "${A}" =~ $regex ]] && B="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
$ echo "${B}"
               <<<=== nothing output
```

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following GNU `grep` solution.

```
grep -oP '^.*? /CLIENT_LOGIN:\K(\S+)' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using GNU `grep`'s `o` and `P` options. Which are responsible for printing exact match and enabling PCRE regex. In main program, using regex `^.*? /CLIENT_LOGIN:\K(\S+)`: which means using lazy match from starting of value to till  `/CLIENT_LOGIN:` to match very first occurrence of string. Then using `\K` option to forget till now matched values so tat we can print only required values, which is followed by `\S+` which means match all NON-Spaces before any space comes.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `awk`'s `match` function along with its `split` function to print the required value.

```
awk '
match($0,/\/CLIENT_LOGIN:[^[:space:]]+/){
  split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),arr,":")
  print arr[2]
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Using GNU `awk`'s `FPAT` option please try following solution. Simple explanation would be, setting `FPAT` to `/CLIENT_LOGIN:` followed by all non-spaces values. In main program of `awk` using `sub` to substitute everything till `:` with NULL for first field and then printing first field.

```
awk -v FPAT='/CLIENT_LOGIN:[^[:space:]]+' '{sub(/.*:/,"",$1);print $1}'  Input_file
```

Comment: love the grep solution!

Answer (score 0):

Fixing your `awk` command, you can use

```sh
A="/CLIENT_IPADDR:23.4.28.2 /CLIENT_LOGIN:xdfmb1d /MXJ_C"
B=$(echo "$A" | awk 'match($0,/\/CLIENT_LOGIN:[^[:space:]]+/){print substr($0,RSTART+14,RLENGTH-14)}')
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/290GVE) yielding `xdfmb1d`. *Details*:

- `\/CLIENT_LOGIN:` - a `/CLIENT_LOGIN:` string
- `[^[:space:]]+` - one or more non-whitespace chars

The pattern above is what `awk` searches for, and once matched, the part of this match value after `/CLIENT_LOGIN:` is "extracted" using `substr($0,RSTART+14,RLENGTH-14)` (where 14 is the length of the  `/CLIENT_LOGIN:` string).

Comment: Tried the exact code with A="/CLIENT_IPADDR:23.4.28.2 /CLIENT_LOGIN:xdfmb1d /MXJ_C" and it did not work (empty result).

Comment: @mfnx The input is quite different here. You may use `B=$(echo "$A" | awk 'index($2, "/CLIENT_LOGIN"){sub(/.*:/,"",$2); print $2}')`, see [this online demo](https://ideone.com/GwiSPp). When you ask a question, please do not oversimplify  sample strings.

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to treat 100 cases... I just wanted to extract the word after /CLIENT_LOGIN: